# Растянуть <div> через заданную width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Есть два `<div>`:

```
 <div id='const_width' style='width: 1170px;'>
     <div id='set_length' style='width: 100%;'>Моя мечта - быть растянутым на всю страницу</div>
 </div>
```

Как растянуть div `set_length` на всю страницу по ширине?
Получается, если экран большой, то `set_length` растянут на `1170px`. А мне нужно на всю ширину экрана

Как это сделать с помощью `css`+`js`?

Comment: Он у вас растянут на 100% только родительского блока.

Comment: Если только с помощью скрипта

Comment: родительский блок у вас 1170рх а вот чилд уже на 100% родителя (который 1170рх в инлайн стиле) и чилд ни как не ратянется на 100% экрана если только через позиционирование + js

Comment: почему родительский блок нельзя растянуть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменять нужно только в CSS проценты :)

```js
$(function() {
  var e = $('.two'), p0 = $('.one'), p1 = $('body');
  var w = (e.outerWidth() / p0.outerWidth()) * p1.outerWidth();
  e.css({width: w});
});
```

```css
.one {width:300px;height:50px;border:1px solid black}
.two {width:100%;height:50px;background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я ни когда не понимал , для чего растягивать чилда ? Это не придирка а вопрос для "поумнения"

Comment: @Geyan, если честно, я сам не понимаю. Мне никогда не приходилось такое делать. Может у кого-то ситуация возникла такая)

Comment: я сто процентов даю что просто для развлечения

Comment: @Geyan, ну не знаю. Когда-то уже задавали этот вопрос. Может и правда кому-то нужно

Comment: @Geyan, единственное было. Когда создаёшь одностраничник с центрированным главным блоком, нужно одиу из категорий сделать не  внутри, а что бы она была от края до края страницы. Может по этому

Comment: Согласен, но для этого не надо js , хватит расположить блоки правильно , и обычным css оформить ... если честно похоже просто на шляпу какую то ...

Comment: @Yuri Да, оно) На yii2 сайт пишу, хочу красивый большой `<div>` сделать. Нашел еще способ - с абсолютной позиции просто объявить
`left: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: @Geyan, можно и без js. Ну он хочет растянуть внутренний, вот код, как это сделать, а там пусть сам решает)

Comment: @MrKlonwar, с абсолютным проблемы иногда возникают) Ну если у вас работает, то хорошо)

Comment: в любом случае Вы молодец , +5 от меня .. p:s для опера есть дополнение от SO , приходят уведомления .. для меня это новенькое ..

Comment: @Geyan, у меня Chrome. Сейчас гляну, может тут тоже есть

Comment: у меня Хром последнее время лагает не по детски .. пришлось спрыгнуть с него ... опера одно и тоже .. такой же webkit

Comment: @Geyan, попробуйте Mozill'у поюзать. Говорят, что в следующем обновлении Chrom'а не будет лагов

Comment: я линуксоид ... у нас огромное разнообразие броузеров ... и Лиса тоже есть .. она мне нравится но любой webkit удобнее

Comment: @Geyan, это точно